# Run a command each time a file opens, or general syntax

Tags: vim

I have a syntax rule that highlights trailing whitespace:

```
highlight Badspace ctermfg=red ctermbg=red
match Badspace /\s\+$/
```

This is in my `.vimrc`.  It works fine, but the problem is I use splits *a lot*, and it seems that the `match` is only run on the first file you open, as well it should because the `.vimrc` should only run once.

Anyway, how can I get the above syntax to match any file that is opened?  Is there a "general" syntax file?  Is there any other way to run `match` each time a file *opens* rather than just once?  I'd like to know both because I could end up using either one in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach to this problem is actually to use `:syntax` to define a custom `syn-match`.

Try putting this in your vimrc:

```
augroup BadWhitespace
    au!
    au Syntax * syn match customBadWhitespace /\s\+$/ containedin=ALL | hi link customBadWhitespace Error
augroup END
```

**Edit:** It should also be noted that there is built-in support for highlighting trailing whitespace with the `'list'` option; see `:help 'listchars'` and `:h hl-SpecialKey` (`SpecialKey` is the highlight group used to highlight trailing whitespace characters when `'list'` is on).

Comment: That is susceptible to changes of the filetype, `:syntax on/off` commands, etc., and it may even affect the original syntax highlighting. In that respect, `:match` is better suited. See also the discussions on the Vim Tips Wiki page I linked to in my answer.

Comment: @QuinnStrahl is there any way to get this to work for files that have no syntax selected (such as those without an extension?)

Comment: You don't necessarily have to have a filetype associated with the file, as long as you have `syntax` on. You could simply define this "bad whitespace" syntax into every buffer Vim adds, if you wanted. Using the code in my answer as it is right now, simply doing `:syntax on` *should* work.

Comment: I've also updated the answer with information about the `'list'` option, which may be relevant to your interests.

Answer (score 3):

The `:match` command applies the highlighting to a *window*, so you can use the `WinEnter` event to define an `:autocmd`.

```
:autocmd WinEnter * match Badspace /\s\+$/
```

Note that there are already a number of plugins for this purpose, most based on this VimTip: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces

They handle all that for you, and turn off the highlighting in insert mode; some can also automatically delete the whitespace. In fact, I have written a set of plugins for that, too: [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966).

Comment: This would cause the command to fire every time the user enters a window, which is unnecessary; it should only fire once: when the buffer is loaded.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong; `:match` is window-local, not buffer-local. It has to be done on `WinEnter`.

Comment: Yes, and I wouldn't worry about the superfluous calls when entering the same window repeatedly too much; fortunately, the `:match` command already has the right "override previous" semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this by using an `autocmd`:

```
highlight Badspace ctermfg=red ctermbg=red
autocmd BufEnter * match Badspace /\s\+$/
```

However, there's another way to accomplish your specific goal of marking trailing whitespace.  Vim has a built-in feature for highlighting "special" whitespace, which includes tabs (to differentiate from spaces), trailing whitespace, and non-breaking spaces (character 160, which looks like a normal space but isn't).

See `:help list` and `:help listchars`.  Here's what I use:

```
set list listchars=tab:>·,trail:·,nbsp:·,extends:>
```

`listchars` has the benefit of working with any file type, and marking up multiple whitespace types that are of interest.  It is also a lot faster (match will be noticeably slow on giant files) and built-in already.

(Note that those are funky non-ASCII dot characters, which should work fine for you if you cut-and-paste into a UTF8-capable Vim.  If they don't work for you, you can use any characters you like there, such as periods or underscores).

Here's what it looks like for me:

[image]

Comment: That's great, but I'd prefer the space just be highlighted with a background and nothing else.

Comment: This would cause the command to fire every time the user enters a buffer, not just when the buffer is loaded.

Comment: Actually, the issue is that `:match` is window-local, not buffer-local; `WinEnter` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

<s>This is accomplished using `autocmd`. The events you're looking for are `BufWinEnter` and `VimEnter`. From the Vim manual:</s>

### BufWinEnter

```
After a buffer is displayed in a window.  This
can be when the buffer is loaded (after
processing the modelines) or when a hidden
buffer is displayed in a window (and is no
longer hidden).
Does not happen for |:split| without
arguments, since you keep editing the same
buffer, or ":split" with a file that's already
open in a window, because it re-uses an
existing buffer.  But it does happen for a
":split" with the name of the current buffer,
since it reloads that buffer.
```

### VimEnter

```
After doing all the startup stuff, including
loading .vimrc files, executing the "-c cmd"
arguments, creating all windows and loading
the buffers in them.
```

Try putting this in your vimrc:

```
augroup BadWhitespace
    au!
    au VimEnter,BufWinEnter * match Badspace /\s\+$/
augroup END
```

Do `:help autocmd` for more info.

**This is completely wrong because `:match` is window-local, not buffer-local.** [Ingo Karkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat) has the right idea. Unfortunately, there is no good way to avoid triggering the autocmd every time you enter the window.

More to the point, though, this is a job for a custom `syntax`, not `match`.

Comment: What's the difference between `BufWinEnter` and `WinEnter`?

Comment: `BufWinEnter` happens when a Buffer becomes displayed in a window. `WinEnter` happens when the cursor enters a window.